# Has any author ever attempted to explain Magneto's fitness and longevity?

Tags: x-men, magneto

Many superheros have their origins in/around world war 2 or older events, Wonder woman was a nurse, captain america was a soldier, but other these characters very super powers explain their lack of aging and general fitness. Other characters who have a defined back story, like Batman or the Flash, rely less on real-world dateable events.

Magneto on the other hand, in the year 2019, is getting a bit old for his backstory -- which is integral to his character motivations. Having survived the holocaust he wants to prevent the same thing from happening to mutants. Even assuming he were born in the last year of WWII, he'd be 75; more likely at least 80 given he was old enough to remember it.

To my knowledge he has no powers that would keep him from aging or showing infirmity, yet he's generally shown as middle aged or slightly older and still very fit. Has any author attempted to explain this away in universe?

(Obviously the out of universe explanation is he's recognizable with a relatable story and marvel wants to keep cashing in)

Comment: You know all those magnet healing bracelets in the 90s? That is how he stays so fit and so young.

Comment: I would suggest that the ability of many mutants to wield powers requires a significantly more robust constitution than an ordinary human so even without specific healing powers, a mutant like Magneto would tend to be healthier than a human just as he is much more intelligent than the average human -- his body and mind are constituted to handle his magnetic powers and if they were not they would be useless to him -- note that his powers require a good intuitive understanding of how magnetism works.